# Asking for right answers for 中级 questions

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I just wanted to ask for the right answers for these questions... 
In these 2 paragraphs, are my 标点符号 right?

1. 我家有五口人，爷爷   、奶奶、爸爸、妈妈和我。爸爸在电脑公司工作，他是一名工程师；妈妈在一所学校教数学，爷爷和奶奶早就退休，但他们也有很多活动；爷爷在老年大学学习书法，他最喜欢说的话是：“活到老，学到老”，奶奶喜欢养花，每天精心伺候我们家四季常开的鲜花。
2. 一位先生来到一个工地看见3个建筑工人在干同样的活，于是他问其中的一位：“你在做什么？”，那个工人回答道：“你没看到我在砌一块砖？”，那位先生又问第二个工人：“你在忙什么？”，他一脸不高兴地回答：“我在做一个窗户”，第三个工人在听到同样的问题时，兴高采烈地说：“我在盖一座大教堂。”

And in this table, which is more suitable to which?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

急急忙忙 地 跑过来|
兴高采烈 地 庆祝胜利|
迫不及代 地 打开了包裹|
迟疑 地 往前走|
生气 地 骂他的孩子|
风趣 地 开了一个玩笑|
热烈 地 欢迎我们|
客气 地 谢绝了他的邀请|
激动 地 说|
得意 地 拿出自己画的画儿

Answer (score 0):

我家有五口人：爷爷、奶奶、爸爸、妈妈和我。爸爸在电脑公司工作，他是一名工程师；妈妈在一所学校教数学；爷爷和奶奶早就退休，但他们也有很多活动。爷爷在老年大学学习书法，他最喜欢说的话是“活到老，学到老”；奶奶喜欢养花，每天精心伺候我们家四季常开的鲜花。

一位先生来到一个工地看见三个建筑工人在干同样的活，于是他问其中的一位：“你在做什么？”那个工人回答道：“你没看到我在砌一块砖？”那位先生又问第二个工人：“你在忙什么？”他一脸不高兴地回答：“我在做一个窗户。”第三个工人在听到同样的问题时，兴高采烈地说：“我在盖一座大教堂。”

My answer to the 标点符号 question. Though the first paragraph can be marked otherwise.